# Spacing issue on MHartls RoR tutorial Sample App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through M. Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial screen casts, which involve making a sample app.

Mr Hartl's code is located here: github.com/railstutorial/sample_app

My code (in progress so it won't be identical to his code) is located here: github.com/PaulHeinemann/sample_app

Mr. Hartls app is online at railstutorial.heroku.com

My unfinished app is at paulsrailstutorial.heroku.com/

For the life of me I can not figure out why my sign up button and any text below it is all bunched up.  I copied the css from MHartl's git repository, but it didn't fix it.  To see the problem compare railstutorial.heroku.com/signup and paulsrailstutorial.heroku.com/signup  The problem also appears in my signin page but i haven't uploaded that yet, so it seams to be a global problem.

Please help me learn how I screwed up.  I'm really new to this whole programing thing, but it seems like the best programmers are thorough, and that is how I want to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install firefox and firebug. Click on the inspect tool near the bug at the bottom left of your browser window. Hover over your form then do the same of your example. You'll find the solution.

Really it's better you do this than I tell you and I don't know how anyone would survive these days without firebug. Let me know if you don't find it after doing this.

Comment: Now why didn't i think of that?  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, So I looked at both site with firebug, but all I could figure out was that it was deferring to my blueprint screen.CSS and was not invoking my custom.CSS, which has the requisite style information.  Why is my custom.css not being invoked?

Comment: Nevermind, got it.  I forgot to put an = sign in the <div class = "field"> area.   dumb of me.  thanks for your help.